# How do I reset a for loop variable in nodejs app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, for-loop

I have an API method in my nodejs app, in one of my controllers I am trying to generate pages on click,
Unfortunately when calling the method my for loop does not reset values to default.

**UPDATE**

Here are my controllers

in my settings.js I have posts object

```
export const settings ={
    posts: {
        cnn: 2,
        bbc: 4,
    }
}
```

in my handlepPages.js I have this method;

```
export const getPages (doc, posts) =>{

    let pages =[1,2,3,4]
  
    for (let index = 0; index < pages.length; index++) {
        doc.text(`${posts.cnn += 5}`)
        console.log('posts.cnn', posts.cnn )
    }
}
```

I am using this function getPages in  my main controllers generatePages

```
import {settings} from './settings';
import {getPages} from './handlePages'

function generatePages(){
  getPages(doc. posts)
    
}

calling generatePages on click,  on console I get this;

posts.cnn 7
posts.cnn 12
posts.cnn 17
posts.cnn 22
```

**Problem**

```
calling again the method it does not start with posts default values it resumes from where it left
```

**Expected results**

> Whenever I call my getPages function, my for loop should start with
> default posts values.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Define `posts` inside the `getPages` function instead of globally?

Comment: I simplified here so that my qn will be simple to understand, the post is dynamically passed to get my pages  function

Comment: Then I guess correct the values before passing it to the function?  It sounds like the code in the question may be simplified to the point of no longer demonstrating the underlying problem.

Comment: in the real example the difference is just posts object is passed to getPages function getPages(posts) that is the different here nothing else

Comment: I'm not sure why you would expect it to reset in `getPages()` when you don't tell it to do anything. If you're passing it in, it'll have value that was passed. You can certainly declare it globally, but then you'll still have to reset it within the function.

Comment: @TheDeadMan: What passes that object to the function?  Can that consuming code "reset" the values before calling the function?  Can the function "reset" the values before executing the loop?  So far the question really just sounds like, "I have a variable with the value 12, and I want it to have the value 2.  How do I set the value of a variable?"

Comment: @mykaf sorry for not adding more information about the problem, I have updated the question, check now and let  me know if my question is understood now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever I call my getPages function, my for loop should start with default posts values.

Define the value inside the function, that way it gets declared and initialized each time the function is called instead of only once globally:

```
function getPages(doc){
  let posts={
    cnn: 2,
    bbc: 4,
  }
  for (let index = 0; index < pages.length; index++) {
    doc.text(`${posts.cnn += 5}`)
    console.log('posts.cnn', posts.cnn )
  }
}
```

---

Or, based on a comment on the question above...

> in the real example the difference is just posts object is passed to getPages function getPages(posts)

In that case you can simply pass the values you want to the function:

```
getPages({ cnn: 2, bbc: 4 }, doc);
```

Or "reset" the value within the function:

```
function getPages(posts, doc){
  posts.cnn = 2;
  for (let index = 0; index < pages.length; index++) {
    doc.text(`${posts.cnn += 5}`)
    console.log('posts.cnn', posts.cnn )
  }
}
```

---

Essentially, whatever the "real code" is doing... If you want the value passed to `getPages` to always be `2` then either always pass a `2` to `getPages` or immediately set the value to `2` inside of `getPages`.

Comment: Thanks, David for your suggestions, I have updated the question due to qns u asked above. I hope now my qn is much better

Comment: @TheDeadMan: But why can't you simply do `posts.cnn = 2;` at the start of the function?  You're still just asking how to set a value to `2`.  You do that by setting the value to `2`.